# The second dimension in multi-dimension array never reached, why?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Can someone explain for me why this code does not work:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        $arr[$i][$j] = $i.$j; 
    }
 }

 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){ // line 8 = error
         echo  $key." ".$key2."<br />";
     }
 }
?>
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\script\index.php on line 8

I simply cannot understand why I get this error. The array $arr should be initiated with values in its both dimensions. RIght?

Comment: Output the `$arr` array just after creating it with `print_r($arr)` to see it's structure and verify that it is what you think it is.

Comment: This code snippet worked for me (php v5.3.8).

Comment: It's got to be something else. Here's a demo of your code: http://ideone.com/sruJ2. The only difference is that I replaced `"<br />"` for `PHP_EOL` for a cleaner output.

Comment: @Ayman: php_eol would only be relevant when running from console. Switching to it will make webbased output ugly instead. Can't have it both ways.

Comment: @MarcB, [ideone](http://ideone.com/sruJ2) emulates a console output, therefore I had to use `PHP_EOL` for a cleaner output.

Comment: I found the problem. 

In my other code (where I had the problem) I had declared the arr[][] array once more earlier in the code (but inside an if statement). I forgot that, unlike Java, variables declared inside a statement are always reachable elsewhere in PHP, even outside that statement. So when I tried to add elements to the (earlier declared) array, I mixed the indices with different values.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it, and got this as the output with WAMP 2.2:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

Are you using the latest wamp? try downloading and installing the new one.